# JavaScript, detect when the mouse cursors is not over any element

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent

Maybe there is a simple solution to this that I'm overlooking, however I cannot find anything in my research that answers this question.

**I want to know if my mouse cursor is not hovering over ANY element**

For example, say my page has one textbox.  When the mouse cursor moves over the textbox, nothing happens.  When the mouse cursor leaves the textbox, this event fires.

I've tried the following, however the event always fires.

```
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event){
    if (event.target === document.body){
        console.log('fire');
    }
});
```

As always, performance is a major consideration.

Comment: You could try doing the inverse. What about trying '!==' instead of  '===' ?

Comment: you could use `mouseover` wich is not fired quite that often. You'd still have to keep the condition as this event bubbles up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following

```js
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event){
    if (event.target.tagName === "HTML" || event.target.tagName === "BODY"){
        console.log('fire');
    }
});
```

```html
<div>My content</div>
```

Comment: Indeed this seems to work, however it does not for my code... which leads me think the problem must be somewhere else in my code.  However, your solution is correct for this particular problem, so a thank you is in order!